# pagination method for setting the limit is not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular

```
setLimit(limit){
        this.maxLimitMessage=false;
        if(limit>=101)
            this.maxLimitMessage=true;            
            this.toastsManager.error("max limit cannot be more than 100",limit, this.limit);            
            this.limit=100;            
            return;
        }        
        this.toastsManager.error('vbnm')
        this.limit = limit;                        
    }
```

In this method I want that if value is more than 100, then automatically greater value would equal to 100. But in this, it is not working.

Comment: Pls provide more info. What pagination tool you are using? When you say not working `this.limit` is not set to 100 or pagination limit in UI is not set to 100?

Comment: is `limit` as a parameter a string?

Comment: yes, I am passing limit as a parameter. So basically the problem I am facing is if the value is less than 100 then it will go out of the loop and will sucessfully run. But if value if greater than 100 then value is not being equal to 100